# Parsing XML using python and form a list of values

Tags: python, json, xml, tree

Here's the XML:

```
 <root>
   <body>
      <node1>1</node1>
      <node2>2</node2>
      <node3>
           <nodea>abc</nodea>
           <nodeb>bca></nodeb>
           <nodec>
               <nodeq>
                   <nodeqs>@gmail</nodeqs>
               </nodeq>
               <nodeq>
                    <nodeqs>@yahoo</nodeqs>
               </nodeq>
           </nodec>
     </node3>
   </body>
 </root>
```

I need to form the records like:

```
[1,2,'abc','bca', '@gmail']
[1,2,'abc','bca', '@yahoo']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and the findall method (xpath)

```
x="""
<root>
<body>
  <node1>1</node1>
  <node2>2</node2>
  <node3>
       <nodea>abc</nodea>
       <nodeb>bca</nodeb>
       <nodec>
           <nodeq>
               <nodeqs>@gmail</nodeqs>
           </nodeq>
           <nodeq>
                <nodeqs>@yahoo</nodeqs>
           </nodeq>
       </nodec>
 </node3>
 </body>
</root>"""

info = list()

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(x))
for i in tree.findall('//*/'):
    if i.text.strip():
        print type(i)
        print i.text
        info.append(i.text)

print info >  ['1', '2', 'abc', 'bca', '@gmail', '@yahoo']
```

Comment: Even, we have tried that way earlier, but result should be some thing like [[1,2,'abc','bca', '@gmail'], [1,2,'abc','bca', '@yahoo']]